# Can someone explain part *(int*) and how it have any relations to the bitset?

Tags: c++, pointers, bitset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //from float to bits
    float f;
    cin >> f;
    int x = *(int*)&f;
    cout << x << "\n";
    bitset<sizeof(int) * 8> binary(x);
    cout << binary;
}
```

What does the `*(int*)&` do that makes `bitset` work?

I can understand that `&f` makes it the address and `x= sizeof` address `f`? (maybe) but how does it work in `bitset<sizeof(int)>` and what does the `* 8` do?

Comment: Note that `int x = *(int*)&f;` is [a strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and undefined behavior.

Comment: out of curiosity, where did you find that code?

Comment: This is actually an old C hack. `float` and `int` may have the same size (may but not must).  `*(int*)&f` is a "reinterprete" cast. It re-interpretes the storage of `float f` as it was an `int`. With `int` the bit arithmetic can be applied to evaluate / isolate the bits. Nevertheless - it's an old C hack and not valid anymore in C++. (I'm even not sure whether this is still allowed in modern C.)

Comment: `sizeof(int) * 8` multiplies the size of `int` with 8 to obtain the number of bits. (`sizeof` returns the number in Bytes.)

Comment: The C++ equivalent is using `std::memcpy` to copy the bits from the `float` into an `int`.

Comment: do you want to get explained how you can examine the bits of a `float` or do you want to get this particular code explained? Thats quite different questions, because the code is not valid C++

Comment: I actually wanted to know how to change float to bits through this code but quickly understood that this code is invalid

Comment: `f` is a `float`.  `x = *(int *)&f` has undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation).    With a lot of compilers, if `int` and `float` have the same type, it has the effect of producing an `int` with the same bit-wise representation as `f`.

Answer (score 4):

> What does the `*(int*)&` do that makes bitset work?

That's a sequence of three unary operators, `*`, `(int *)`, and `&`.  As used in the code presented, `*(int*)&f` first computes a pointer to `f` (of type `float *`), then the C-style cast converts that to type `int *`, and finally the `*` dereferences that to get a value of type `int`.  Overall, this ...

```
int x = *(int*)&f;
```

... is roughly equivalent to ...

```
int x = reinterpret_cast<int&>(f);
```

... including that **both elicit undefined behavior**.  But the intention is that the representation of `f`'s value is interpreted as an `int`.

> how it have any relations to the bitset?

`std::bitset` has a constructor that accepts an integer argument, which initializes the bitset from the bits of the argument's value.  There is no such constructor that accepts a `float`, and a normal value conversion from type `float` to type `int` does not preserve the bit pattern of the `float`.

<s>It would be better to use a `union` to perform such a conversion:</s>

```
union { float f; int x; } u;

cin >> u.f;
cout << u.x << "\n";
bitset<sizeof(int) * 8> binary(u.x);
cout << binary;
```

In C, you could use a union for that, but in C++, you need another solution, such as `memcpy()`:

```
float f;
int x;

cin >> f;
memcpy(&x, &f, sizeof(x));
cout << x << "\n";
bitset<sizeof(int) * 8> binary(x);
cout << binary;
```

Comment: Isn't type punning with unions in C++ prohibited as well? (in opposition to C where it's still allowed with certain (reasonable) constraints) I believe as well (like mentioned in one of the comments), the correct way would be to use a `memcpy()` or, maybe, using a cast to `char*`.

Comment: You're right, @Scheff'sCat.  Answer revised.